# import Only CakePHP Html Helpers in Custom MVC project

Tags: cakephp

I have an unusual task at hand, I just need to import a specific portion of CakePHP framework in my custom MVC project, i.e HTML helpers.

Can anyone tell me what code libraries from CakePHP do I need to transfer into my project , to do this.

Please note I need only HTML helpers from the CakePHP framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the CakePHP Github repository Helper directory and download them:  https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper

Comment: Hi and Thank you for the response , How will I use this in my code , my views are not classes and I dont have access to the this keyword...to access it as this->Html->link()

Comment: @Taz - they're just PHP classes.  Unfortunately "how to use a PHP class" is beyond the scope of something answerable here.  If you try some thing(s) and have a specific issue, by all means, ask another question. :)

Comment: Well sorry about that I have used cakePHP earlier versions and not 2.x we used to access the methods like $html->link()...I just misunderstood $this to be this keyword....

Comment: The Issue I am having is the HtmlHelper class is using methods that are not there in PHP itself ....e.g a custom defined sprintf() method which it returns when I try to create a link.

Comment: `sprintf()` is a PHP method, not specific to CakePHP